# How to extend supported database of flyway？

Tags: flyway

We have seen flyway framework for database migration. It is pretty wonderful. In our project, we are using GuassDB as database which flyway not support yet. Could you please let me kown how to make it work or will GuassDB be supported in future ? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few examples if you go through http://github.com/flyway/flyway/pulls - and if you don't mind waiting a day or so we will be adding more detailed instructions to the Flyway website with the 6.2 release. You will be able to find it here:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/contributingDatabaseSupport

We generally check [DB-Engines ranking](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking) to get a feel for the level of support for each database platform before we commit to supporting it, as well as an ability to run our test suite against it.

Comment: Get it.Thank you!